# Designing and developing a responsive website media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I need help when designing and developing a responsive website.

I know it's not code as such and I'm sure i'll get marked down for this but it is a developer question.

I'm only just developing my first responsive theme and I want to make sure I get it right before I go any further.

At the moment I'm designing it at 1000px's wide, this way I thought it would be easier to calculate for smaller screens when designing.

My first question is, what sizes should I design for? if I have the main desktop screen at 1000px, what should a laptop, tablet and mobile be?

Here's the layouts i'm designing to at the moment, is this even correct?

Desktop: 1000px
laptop : 800px
tablet (Portrait): 768 px
phone: 568px

Then you come to media queries, at the moment i'm using the following:

for phones

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : portrait) { 
}
```

for tablets

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
}
```

for laptops

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
}
```

for desktops

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many people says nowadays, it's you content who decide for breakpoints. The rule it's easy when your content breaks add a breakpoint.

You can use new developper tools (who give you the list of device width and height) from [chrome canary](http://www.google.com/intl/fr/chrome/browser/canary.html) [explained here](http://girliemac.com/blog/2014/07/28/devicemode/) or adaptive mode in firefox. Or you can look [here](http://mydevice.io/devices/) for more device sizes.

One more thing, Brad Frost have a nice tool to test your site [ish](http://bradfrostweb.com/demo/ish/). And he make a big big list of many patterns and tools [here](http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/).
Hope it gonna help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the links they really help and I'll certainly use them, i'm still a little confused about the design stage though? Do I just design for the desktop then use the browser tools to determine how it will look on a mobile / tablet?

Comment: Design for mobile at first something like :
.main-div { rules } and add breakpoints for bigger screens after, like that you don't need to rewrite your rules, because every screen goona have your mobile rules. You add breakpoints (of course you can start with Bokdem css-tricks exemple, but carefull article wasn't updated since 2010) when you saw that it brokes.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i just build a design in Photoshop using a grid. I keep the 360px, 480px and 1024px in the back of my mind.

When building, i make changes to my code whenever my design gets 'ruined' due to window-sizes starting at mobile-first. 
After all, this is just my personal opinion and way of building.

Down here are some queries that might be useful:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

**Source: [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)**

Comment: Thanks for the input, how do you know that the website doesn't work on certain devices and might need adjusting?

Comment: Within Chrome's developer-tools you can find the option to emulate your website for over 30 devices. You could use that to test your development.

Comment: Still, building your web design for every device there is will not be the best option there is. You will never be able to serve all of them correctly. As i mentioned before, try building till something breaks and make an edit for that specific dimensions. Don't take the design accurate by the pixel exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you already have some great answers here.

Just try to share some idea from my experiences. I usually start from the content first and the target audience. If the website mainly gonna be accessed from desktop/laptop, then I start at least with the 1024px-wide screen. From this I could consider 4 type of screen sizes:

1. 'Basic' : default width ~ 1024px
2. 'Wide' : big screen, larger than the basic
3. 'Tablet' (medium-sized)
4. 'Mobile' (small-sized)

Related to Bokdem's answer, you don't have to push yourself to be precisely design for every device available out there - you may go totally insane doing that. Therefore, for testing the responsive design you could as simple as using one of the add-ons, '[web developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)', if you're using Firefox. Or you can also try [ScreenQueries](http://beta.screenqueri.es/) for online testing.